# Add to Favorite using Custom TableViewCell via UIButton & Save to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, uitableview, userdefaults

Goal: Create an "add to favorites" button in a Custom TableViewCell which then saves the list of favorites into UserDefaults such that we can get a tableview of favorites only. (I'm using segmentedControl as the means to filter where `libraryFilter = 0`(Plan) / 1 = Tag / 2 = Duration / 3 = Favorite)

`jsonErgWorkouts` is the array of workouts from a JSON file which is the basis of the filtering.

This is my what I have coded up.

Custom TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class ErgWorkoutCell: UITableViewCell {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var ergWorkoutTitle: UILabel! 
}
```

In the TableView View Controller

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let selectedGroup = selectedWorkoutGroup(libraryFilter: libraryFilter, jsonErgWorkouts: jsonErgWorkouts, workoutGroupBox: workoutGroupBox)
    
    /// this is cast AS! ErgWorkoutCell since this is a custom tableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ergWorkoutCell") as! ErgWorkoutCell
    
    cell.ergWorkoutTitle.text = selectedGroup[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
  }
}


func selectedWorkoutGroup(libraryFilter: Int, jsonErgWorkouts:[workoutList], workoutGroupBox: UITextField) -> [workoutList] {
  var selectedGroup = [workoutList]()
    
  if libraryFilter == 0 { // Segmented Control #1 (Plan)
    selectedGroup = jsonErgWorkouts.filter { $0.group == workoutGroupBox.text }
  /// code for libraryFilter 1(Tag)
  ///      and libraryFilter 2(Duration) 
  } else if libraryFilter == 3 {
    // Need code here to return the filtered JSON of favorites only
  }
  
  return selectedGroup
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have several unexplained variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things needed to be done. I'll also link some of the SO pages which contributed to get to this solution.

1. Add a button into storyboard
2. Add a Button definition (IBOutlet/IBAction) & a closure into Custom TableViewCell
3. Add a way to Store the selected Favorite into UserDefaults
4. Show the list of Favorites in the segmentedControl.

Let's get started:

1. **Add a button into Storyboard**

   I'll leave this to the user
2. **Add a Button definition (IBOutlet/IBAction) & a closure into Custom TableViewCell**

   ```
   import UIKit
   class ErgWorkoutCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var ergWorkoutTitle: UILabel!

     /// Create and Connect your Button outlet
     @IBOutlet weak var ergWorkoutFavBtn: UIButton!

     /// create your closure here
     /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743790/14414215
     var favButtonPressed : (() -> ()) = {}

     /// Create & Connect an IBAction when your button is pressed. 
     @IBAction func ergWorkoutFavBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
       /// Call your closure here
       favButtonPressed()
     }
   }
   ```
3. **Add a way to Store the selected Favorite into UserDefaults**

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357869/14414215
   /// https://stackoverflow.com/q/65355061/14414215
   /// Provide an initial default (empty array) to the UserDefaults Array since on startup there is no fav in the list.
   var rowsWhichAreChecked = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "workoutFavorite") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

   /// this is cast AS! ErgWorkoutCell since this is a custom tableViewCell
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ergWorkoutCell") as! ErgWorkoutCell

   cell.ergWorkoutTitle.text = selectedGroup[indexPath.row].title

   /// This is to change the image between favourited or Not
   if rowsWhichAreChecked.contains(selectedGroup[indexPath.row].id) {
     cell.ergWorkoutFavBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-full"), for: .normal)
   } else {
     cell.ergWorkoutFavBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-empty"), for: .normal)
   }

   /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743790/14414215
   /// Once the FavButton is pressed, we determine if the selected item is already 
   /// in the FavList. If Yes, we remove it, if Not, we add it in.
   /// We then reload the table
   /// Added [ weak self] in based on @azehe
   /// https://stackoverflow.com/q/64297651/14414215
   cell.favButtonPressed = { [ weak self ] in
     if rowsWhichAreChecked.contains(selectedGroup[indexPath.row].id) {
       let removeIdx = rowsWhichAreChecked.lastIndex(where: {$0 == selectedGroup[indexPath.row].id})
       rowsWhichAreChecked.remove(at: removeIdx!)

       cell.ergWorkoutFavBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-empty"), for: .normal)
     } else {
       cell.ergWorkoutFavBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-full"), for: .normal)
       rowsWhichAreChecked.append(selectedGroup[indexPath.row].id)
     }
     UserDefaults.standard.set(rowsWhichAreChecked, forKey: "workoutFavorite")
     self?.vcLibTableView.reloadData() // self? instead of self (with [weak self] in
   }
     return cell
   }
   ```
4. **Show the list of Favorites in the segmentedControl.**

```
   func selectedWorkoutGroup(libraryFilter: Int, jsonErgWorkouts:[workoutList], workoutGroupBox: UITextField) -> [workoutList] {
     var selectedGroup = [workoutList]()
     
     /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357869/14414215
     let workoutFav = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "workoutFavorite") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

     if libraryFilter == 0 {
       selectedGroup = jsonErgWorkouts.filter { $0.group == workoutGroupBox.text }
     } else if libraryFilter == 1 {
       /// https://stackoverflow.com/q/65355061/14414215
       selectedGroup = workoutFav.flatMap { favouriteId in // for each favourite ID
             jsonErgWorkouts.filter { $0.id == favouriteId }
      } // flatMap joins all those arrays returns by "filter" together, no need to do anything else
     }
     
     return selectedGroup
   }
```

[image: Result]

Adding `[weak self] in`  based on input from @azehe comment. You can see the difference in the Memory Graph.
[image: Debug Memory Graph differences]

Comment: You might need a `[weak self]` inside `cell.favButtonPressed = {`

Comment: @aheze Could you elaborate? I'm a beginner Swift and I dun know how/why that would be used even after reading https://www.donnywals.com/when-to-use-weak-self-and-why/ and I also tried putting  ```cell.favButtonPressed = { [weak self]``` but it resulted in an error/. Thanks.

Comment: you will also need an `in`, `cell.favButtonPressed = { [weak self] in`

Comment: So inside `favButtonPressed`, you are capturing an instance of `self` in `self.vcLibTableView.reloadData()`. I am not very good with closures, but I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64297651/14351818) about this that might help you

Comment: @azehe Thanks!! I think it makes a difference. I tried the memory graph thing and can see a big difference.